# Color Text in spinner in Android ICS (Holo.light)

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a problem with the text color of spinner in Android ICS (with Holo.Light theme).
The problem is that the background color is light grey, and the text color is white, and can't be seen the text.

Looking in stackoverflow, I found how to change the text color when is dropdown the spinner, but not the color when the spinner isn't dropdown
Someone can help me fix it?

I tried to tag android: textColor and does not work.
The code I use is the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When ever you set the adapter for Spinner, you are passing in a ResourceID of a TextView I guess. So change the font color of that TextView in layout xml will solve this.

Comment: Thanks, It's works, I created an xml file with a TextView and I have assigned the color with textColor.
I don't understand because it was not working using android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item without modifying the theme or assigning any color

Comment: I've had a similar issue and it was because when setting the adapter we were passing in application context, not the activity...

Answer (score 5):

To get black text (in Theme.Holo.Light) instead of white, if you're using an ArrayAdapter, have the Context be `getActivity().getBaseContext()` because `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in my experience will give you white text.

So like this:

```
final Spinner num = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.num_spinner);
String[] spinnerArray = {"1", "2", "3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
num.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Took me forever to figure this out, because I was using the Application Context. **!@$!#$**

Comment: very good answer. I think this should be the accepted answer. Why to create another layout just to change the color? Your idea of settings activity as the context is the best

Comment: I was about to quit Android development for ever, thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. this will change the color of your view. If any problem ask again.

```
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
        TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.getSelectedView();
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while putting a spinner inside a DialogFragment.  Since I couldn't use "this" as the context, I used the application context.  This caused the spinner to show white text on a gray background:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mApplication, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerOptions);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

The white text was caused because my activity was using the style Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, but the spinner was unaware of it. By changing the context from **mApplication** to **getActvity()** the spinner now knows to use Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog when inflating the views:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerOptions);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Now I have black text on a gray background.

Comment: but from where you get application context??.. same thing i m facing i m in fragment tab i had set dark them to display tab now spiner i want light them in contex i can only pass getActivty(), there is no getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Pankaj You don't want getApplicationContext(), as that gives white text. There should be a getActivity().getBaseContext() and that will give you black text!

Answer (score 1):

change the getActivity() to "this", dont know the reason but it works fine..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerOptions);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```